# wordpress admin can't access plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, privileges

Using a WordPress 4.3.1 multisite, only super-admins can see and use one specific plugin (Appointments Scheduler) which is supposed to be present in the left menu bar.

The plugin is definitely activated in the network and is completely operable by super-admins.

Problem: Administrators on the sub-site cannot see the plugin, nor can they access it by direct URL. It claims they don't have privileges to access the plugin.

The plugin has no "settings" or "privileges" sections.

This sub-site and the plugin were imported into the multisite. Prior to this, when it was a stand-alone, the administrators had no problem accessing it.

Comment: I recommend contacting the plugin author.

Comment: Thank you, I emailed them directly a few hours ago. Felt like posting here just in case I can get a quicker fix.